# how to improve : Two Sum Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers... using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I was looking for better solution to the leetcode problem mentioned below.

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

```js
let twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        for(let j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a Map to do this in O(n) time. Iterate over each number (let say num) in the array and check if `target - num` is already present in the map. If it is present, it means that in previous iterations we have already seen a number which when added to current num returns the target. And in each iteration we are putting the current num as key and it's index as value in the Map.

```js
const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    const map = new Map();

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        const diff = target - nums[i];
        if (map.has(diff)) {
            return [map.get(diff), i];
        }
        map.set(nums[i], i);
    }

    return [];
};
console.log(twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 9));
```

Comment: it should return [4,5]

Comment: The numbers 4 and 5 sum upto 9, the index of 4 is 3 and index of 5 is 4. I think the output is correct

Comment: Can anyone help, why shoudn't we create a map/set of object in first run and than directly check for diff in map? In both the base space complexity will be same.